# Mostrar nombre y extension de un archivo al editar form usando gema carrierwave en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy usando la gema `carrierwave` para subir documentos en mi proyecto, y funciona perfecto, mi problema es cuando quiero edita el formulario, ya teniendo previamente un documento guardado, el botón para subir un documento o imagen me aparece con la leyenda "No se selecciono un archivo";

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que diga el nombre del archivo y su extensión, por ejemplo `doc.pdf`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el código :

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :avatar, "Foto de Perfil" %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar  ,class: "btn btn-info btn-sm"%> 
</div>
```

Comment: El input de tipo file es solo para subir archivos. Si quieres mostrar qué archivo has subido, tienes que hacer la lógica que muestre eso.

Comment: Pero como podria agregar a la leyenda  "No se selecciono un archivo" el nombre del archivo que si existe?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes. De hecho ese texto del input file es manejado por el explorador y es distinto dependiendo del que uses o el idioma de tu sistema.
Lo que puedes hacer es [ocultar el input y manejar el adjunto a través de un label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822113/895789) o, insisto, que muestres un texto que muestre el nombre del archivo si es que ya lo adjuntaste. Algo como:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :avatar, "Foto de Perfil" %>
  <% if tumodelo.avatar.file.exists? %>
    <%= tumodelo.avatar.file.filename %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar  ,class: "btn btn-info btn-sm"%> 
</div>
```